# How to uninstall angular packaged library

Tags: angular6, angular5, angular7

I have installed example-app using this command npm install --save example-app but i can not uninstall this library So how to uninstall this npm package?

Not working

```
       npm uninstall --save example-app
```

Comment: Not absolutely sure how it works on windows but you could try to manually remove `example-ng-lib-app` from your node_module directory and delete the specific line from your package.json file.

Comment: @TGrif:  Any other way is there? using command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

1)
npm uninstall example-ng-lib-app --save

2)
or delete node_modules directory (you might need to kill the app first).
remove the example-ng-lib-app from package.json in your root directory.
run command: npm install

Comment: Anyother way is there?

Comment: yes. when you want to remove the dependency, you are referencing it by its package name (/example-ng-lib-app), not the actual location